# Does it possible to handle or to recive data on client from websocket every 3s. of course this example doesnt work

Tags: javascript, websocket, setinterval

I tried to do it this way, but of course, it doesn't work

```
this.connection.onmessage = event => {
                    setInterval(() => {
                      console.log(event.data)
                    }, 3000)
                  }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

A Websocket is designed to be event driven.

When the server sends data to your client, the `onmessage` event runs.
What you have done with this code, is to tell client to output the message received from the server every 3 seconds, every time a message is received.

To output data every 3 seconds, the data should be sent every 3 seconds otherwise you are missing the point of Websockets.